# Can't connect despite port forwarding

Tags: apache, networking, portforwarding, ubuntu-server

I have a Ubuntu Server 16.04 running on a machine in my local network. 
The machine has static assigned IP and running apache2. There is no problem in connecting to it from my local network. 
I have port-forwarding for ports 22 and 80 setup on my router to the IP address of the machine. 
When I check the ports with my public IP address on sites like http://www.canyouseeme.org/ the result is that the ports are open. When I try to connect using my public IP address and using those ports the connections are refused. 
I tried disabling firewall in the router and also on the machine, no result.

What else should I try? It seems that the server is getting no incoming connection when I check with netstat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for troubleshooting purposes:

- Setup port forwarding on port 22 and try to ssh into your server using the public IP? If it works, it means apache is refusing the connections and not your router or ISP
- On your router, setup the server on the DMZ temporarily and check if it works
- Add another port forwarding rule on your router to redirect all http requests on port 8000,for example, to port 80 internally, then try to access your server with http://[public_ip]:8000

Have you changed anything on the apache2.conf file? Also, explain how you are testing the connection, internally using the public IP or from the Internet?

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to connect from my internal network using the public IP. After trying to connect from the internet it worked. Does it mean that when I want to connect from my internal network I have to use strictly the private address?

Comment: Thank you martin49. Been pulling my hair out trying to port forward. Did what Felipe suggeted on port 22 and it worked From my office servers. Read your comment and used wget from a machine not local and it worked. Now I need to figure out why the public IP won't work when local. Probably something to do with my ISP not allowing loobback.